# next.js does a fetch instead of a redirect with a text/x-component content-type

Tags: next.js, http-headers, response-headers

I have a function in a next.js v13 app router app that ends with a redirect:

```
...
return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl.toString()
```

Instead of redirecting to a page, it instead informs the browser to fetch data (see screenshot).

I noticed the content-type is `text/x-component`. I've tried a `3xx` status on the response. Any way to disable this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Nextjs internal `redirect` function:

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

...

return redirect(redirectUrl.toString());
```

You can read more about Nextjs internal `redirect` function in here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect

Comment: I've tried this and it's still not rendering properly, looks like it does a fetch to grab the page changes, then another to get the page.js but the render still doesn't happen.

Comment: I guess your middleware changes the header. Check the middleware headers please.